# Why does explicit Runge-Kutta 4 allow positive eigenvalues?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, na.numerical-analysis

When solving a system of ODEs:
$$\dot{x} = A x,$$
we call the system unstable when the eigenvalues of A have a positive real part.

However, the stability region of the explicit Runge-Kutta 4 method does allow for some eigenvalues with a positive real part. See the attached picture. Why is that so?

[image: The RK4 stability region]

Comment: What do you mean by "why?" The mathematical justification for the picture above is that for RK4, numerical stability is basically asking whether the matrix $$B_h := 1 + h A + \frac12 h^2 A^2 + \frac16 h^3 A^3 + \frac1{24} h^4 A^4 $$ (here $h$ is the time step size) has eigenvalues with real parts $> 1$. There is an obvious relation between the eigenvalues of $B_h$ and eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $A$. The graph you showed charts that.

Comment: But something like this is surely explained in your numerical analysis textbook and unsuitable for asking on MathOverflow. So can you clarify what you intend to ask? (Mathematical objects don't have agency, so I am not sure how to interpret "why" besides the above "this is how it works.")

Comment: An unstable system is not supposed to have stable solutions. Yet, the solutions to the same system approximated by RK4 are stable. I find that strange.

Comment: The region you are plotting is not star shaped. For a fixed $A$ and a choice of $h$ such that $h\lambda$ has positive real part and lies in the region shown, if you shrink $h$ you can get into the unstable region. You probably want to think of those blobs as "stable by numerical accident".

Comment: Another way to think of it is that for such $A$, you can find a step size for which the numerical scheme is stable, but the numerical solution is not very accurate; and trying to make it more accurate by shrinking the step size $h$ makes it numerically unstable (as you would expect of a fundamentally unstable system).

Comment: That's a good point!

Comment: This is not an appropriate question for MathOverflow.  You could ask it on scicomp.SE, where more basic questions are acceptable.  The short answer to your question is that numerical approximations are in general not guaranteed to preserve the asymptotic stability properties of the systems they approximate.  The study of the relation between the two, and the work to develop discretizations that do preserve such behavior, is a major area of numerical analysis.